# join a column that contains the previous max

Tags: sql, t-sql, join, max

Okay, say i have a table with the field "code". The query `select code from mytable group by code` returns:

```
code
EM010
EM100
EM101
EM105
EM106
...
```

I need to add a column (with a join or something) that will contain the next highest code. The above would turn to:

```
code    code2
EM010   null (or blank or wtvr)
EM100   EM010
EM101   EM100
EM105   EM101
EM106   EM105
...     ...
```

I'd provide what I've tried but it's messy and I keep realizing I'm going about it the wrong way.

btw, i'm working in vfp so it's technically tsql but i should be able to convert anything that's different, so i don't mind if i get answers that haven't been tested in tsql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (Code VARCHAR(5))
INSERT @T VALUES ('EM010'), ('EM100'), ('EM101'), ('EM105'), ('EM106')

SELECT  T1.Code,
        (   SELECT  MAX(Code)
            FROM    @T t2
            WHERE   t1.Code > t2.Code
        ) AS Code2
FROM    @T t1
```

Comment: I ended up doing something like this. In vfp you can't reference things outside of you sub select so: `WHERE t1.Code > t2.Code` doesn't work. I ended up using a sub routine to do the sub select for me.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
WITH T1 AS
(
    SELECT code, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY code) AS rn FROM
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT code FROM mytable
    )
)
SELECT T1.code, T2.code AS code2
FROM T1
LEFT JOIN T1 AS T2
ON T1.rn = T2.rn + 1
```

By the way, in SQL Server 2012 you can use the [LAG](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/11/15/sql-server-introduction-to-lead-and-lag-analytic-functions-introduced-in-sql-server-2012/) analytical function that does what you want. I'm not sure if Visual Fox Pro supports it though.

Comment: ooh i think vfp can do something similar to lag with `top`, I'm looking at it now. It'll be awesome if this works.

Comment: nope, nvm. i like your solution but vfp is more limited than i thought. I don't even have a row_number function. Anyway i solved the problem using gareth's solution and some subroutines to get around vfp's limitations.